# Do I need a visa to visit the UK with my EU family members if I have a Spanish residence card?

Tags: visas, uk, paperwork, family

My wife and son have European passports but I don't. I have a residence card issued by Spain. Can I travel to the UK with my family without applying for a visa?

Comment: Is your wife a citizen of Spain, the UK, or some other EU/EEA country?

Comment: What passport do you hold?

Comment: What phoog said, or Swiss too.

Comment: @BritishSam it's complicated enough without bringing Switzerland into it!  But the point is well taken.

Answer (score 2):

If it's an Article 10 or Article 20 card for family members of an EU/Schengen citizen, then you only need that and your passport.

Otherwise, you need an EEA Family Permit, a free visa.

Answer (score -3):

It is clear that a residence card is not a passport.
Your nationality defines whether you need a visa to enter the UK or not.
You can check it here: https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa
Your residence card issued by Spain gives you the right to apply for a UK visa (if you need one) from Spain.

Comment: "residence card" is a term of art in EU law that denotes a card issued under article 10 or 20 of the free movement directive.  If the question uses the term correctly then the card does exempt its bearer from the visa requirement, subject to certain additional conditions.